# Sample detection events with TableauSimulator

Tags: error-correction, stim

I've been manually driving `stim.TableauSimulator` to simulate more complex noise models like in a [previous post](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/a/27298/26588).

The way I've set up my code is to replace instances of `DEPOLARIZE1` in an input circuit with my own arbitrary classical distribution of Pauli errors via the Tableau simulator.  I can use `TableauSimulator.current_measurement_record` to obtain measurement samples, but what's the most efficient way to obtain detector samples (and hence apply error correction)?

I'm aware of `stim.Circuit.compile_m2d_converter`, but that would require compiling a new circuit with every shot. Is there a better solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to try the new [`stim.FlipSimulator`](https://github.com/quantumlib/Stim/blob/main/doc/python_api_reference_vDev.md#stim.FlipSimulator) instead of the tableau simulator. It's much faster, it will compute detection events for you, and you can still do complicated python-driven noise with it. It just needs to be the case that you only care about whether results are flipped, instead of about what their absolute value is. It's still somewhat bare bones, so let me know if it's missing something you need.

---

To compute detection events with the tableau simulator is quite tricky, because it requires computing the expected value of each detector's measurement set, in order to check if it's flipped. Since you're only changing the noise, you should be able to use [`circuit.reference_sample()`](https://github.com/quantumlib/Stim/blob/main/doc/python_api_reference_vDev.md#stim.Circuit.reference_sample) to get this expectation. More generally you may have some way to know a valid noiseless sample for your specific circuit, e.g. it's somewhat common for QEC circuits to have all-zeros as a valid sample. Anyways, you can do something like this:

```
def compute_detector(
    sim: stim.TableauSimulator,
    entire_circuit_we_are_running: stim.Circuit,
    detector_instruction: stim.CircuitInstruction,
) -> bool:
    assert detector_instruction.name == "DETECTOR"

    # Don't actually do this for every detector. Cache things.
    ref_sample = entire_circuit_we_are_running.reference_sample()
    measurement_record = sim.current_measurement_record()

    result = False
    for t in detector_instruction.targets_copy():
        assert t.is_measurement_record_target
        k = len(measurement_record) + t.value
        result ^= measurement_record[k]
        result ^= ref_sample[k]
    return result
```

The main issue with this method is that it calls `sim.current_measurement_record()` and `circuit.reference_sample()` for every single detector, which is very inefficient. The reference sample you can just store and pass in, instead of recomputing it each time. But the measurement record changes as you do measurements, so you have to keep pulling it. I should probably add some way to get specific record entries without pulling the whole thing.